# javascript Regular Expressions Issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I really need some help in Regular Expressions, i'm working on a function like

```
var x = 0;

function doMath(myVar){

RE = //; // here is the problem 
if(RE.test(myVar))
  eval(x+myVar)
else
return false;

}
```

i want the RE to match any math equation that could be added to that number like

```
EXAMPLE 
+10+20+30 //accepted
**10 //rejected
-10- // rejected
10 // rejected
%10 //accepted
*(10+10)-10 //accepted
```

please help me

}

Comment: Math equations are not a regular language (due to balanced parentheses problems), and thus you really shouldn't be trying to use a single regex to parse it.

Comment: what should i do ? any suggestion ?

Comment: I agree with Dav. If the end goal is to evaluate the expression, then you should try to evaluate it using the postfix method and a stack. http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/postfix-evaluation/index.htm

Comment: @ferrari fan.. that should be posted as an answer

Comment: @ferrari - but how do you convert the expression to postfix notation? That's just as difficult as evaluation the expression in the first place, you still have to parse and understand it correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just do the test for valid characters (to prevent some code injections), and then try "eval"-ing it?

```
function doMath(myVar){
    if (/^[0-9()%*\/+-]+$/.test(myVar)){
        try{
             return eval(myVar);
        }catch(e){}
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I was just writing the same 4 hours ago when by boss came in :P. You should note the validation also prevents code injection (for example, if the text comes from the query string).

Comment: Thanks @Kobi, added few words, but I am not 100% sure, its prevent code injection completely. :-) I havn't see any injections that use only 0-9 and math operators though.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments arithmetic equations are not regular so don't handle them using regular expressions.

Write a [Context-free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) for arithmetic expressions and use a parser generator like [Jison](http://github.com/zaach/jison) that generates a parser in javascript from your given grammar.

**An example CFG for mathemical expressions**

On the [Jison](http://github.com/zaach/jison) page scroll down to the section **"Specifying a language"**. That section gives a language grammar to parse arithmetic expressions. Hope this helps.